# Modern readline implemenation for Python on Windows

Tags: python, readline, python-packaging

I'm looking for a Python package as a modern GNU readline drop-in implementation for Python on Windows 7.

I know about [pyreadline on github](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline), but this implementation is fairly old and when used in Python 3.8 on Windows 7 it gives the warning:

```
py3k_compat.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.9 it will stop working
  return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)
```

So, clearly with Python 3.9 this will break... Apart form the option to fix the source code in py3k_compat.py, I would like to know: Are there other, more modern packages available which can act as drop-in replacements for the readline library on Windows 7?

Comment: you may have similar problem with other modules - maybe stay with 3.7

Comment: I pushed on past the DeprecationWarning and actually tried to use it, ran into an exception relating to ctypes in my application.  So pyreadline is clearly a dead end, and negative karma to gnureadline project for blithely disclaiming even the intent to support windows and blandly recommending pyreadline.  Is gnureadline also a dead project?

Comment: @BobHy My app which uses pyreadline is [xonsh](https://xon.sh) and it behaves *fairly* well. It occasionally freezes, but only sometimes... I do attribute it to the pyreadline iterface though.